# Rails Routing No route matches {:action=>"revert", :controller=>"the_name"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have searched and tried a bunch on different things. None have worked. What am I missing in my routes to cause this error?

```
resources :the_name do
  member do
    get 'revert'
  end
end
```

In my controller

```
def revert
  ...
end
```

My view is calling

```
revert_the_name_path(@some_var)
```

@some_var is just an instance of the model. IE: @some_var = SomeModelName.new

I've tried

```
resources :the_name do
  collection do
    get 'revert'
  end
end
```

Comment: Do a `rake routes | grep revert`. Might help you debug. You definitely need `member` and not `collection`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not work if your instance is new record ( like SomeModelName.new )

You need id to generate a member path. Be sure that @some_var.id is not nil.

Comment: ok so ya this seems to just happen when I go to the new route.

Comment: Ok so this makes perfect since ... thanks. To fix my senario I just check to see if i am editing the record or creating a new one by adding this code in my view: if controller.action_name == 'edit'

Comment: I'm glad if it did help. I can't say i really did understand exactly where and why you are generating this link, but, instead of using `if controller.action_name == 'edit'` you can also use `unless @some_var.new_record?` too.